# three.js - touch events for THREE.RollControls

Tags: three.js

I've used `THREE.RollControls` for movements in a scene of tube geometry.
How do I use `THREE.RollControls` for touch events ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by taking a look at the code for [RollControls](http://threejsdoc.appspot.com/doc/three.js/src.source/extras/controls/RollControls.js.html).  Toward the bottom, you'll see where all the mouse events are bound to their handlers.

To add touch support, you can edit or extend RollControls to respond to touch events.  I'd expect the mousemove, mousedown, and mouseup events to correspond to touchmove, touchstart, and touchend events respectively.